# Как изменить путь по умолчанию в командной строке Windows 10?

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-10

Как настроить путь командной строки Windows 10, чтобы при открытии командная строка всегда была такого образца:

```
D:\works\projects
```

Переходы `cd` не предлагать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Внесите или создайте, если его нет, ключ в реестр по адресу `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` с именем `"Autorun"`, значение которого и будет команда перехода в вашу папку.

Ну, или просто скопируйте в файл temp.reg нижеприведенный текст и запустите:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor]
"Autorun"="cd /d \"D:\\works\\projects\""
```

После внесения (даже без перезагрузки) CMD будет открываться в нужной папке.

Comment: Вобще, это вредный совет. С такой командой изменяется текущий рабочий каталог скрипта, независимо откуда он запускается. Например, если сделать в нем команду `dir`, то он покажет каталог не из того места где запускался, а из текущего рабочего каталога(т.е. `D:\works\projects`)

Comment: @ГеннадийП Согласен. Но тут уже зависит от пользователя, ЧТО ему больше надо. Мне не лениво сделать cd после запуска :)

Comment: Проще сделать ярлык и через него запускаться.

Comment: @ГеннадийП проще создать плагин вида "cmd here", на мой взгляд, но, повторюсь, каждому - своё.

Answer (score 3):

"Путь по умолчанию" на самом деле является текущей директорией, которая была установлена на момент запуска cmd.exe. Если вы открываете командную строку при помощи ярлыка - то эта директория хранится в свойствах ярлыка, под названием "Рабочая папка".

Вот вам пример - стандартный ярлык командной строки в Windows:

[image: скриншот]

Вы можете просто создать новый ярлык, указывающий на cmd.exe, и прописать в качестве рабочей директории любой путь который вам нужен.

Также вы можете дописать любую команду в строку "Объект" используя ключ `/k`, который означает "исполнить команду и оставить командную строку запущенной". В качестве примера попробуйте указать в этой настройке `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /k echo "Hello, world"`.

Если вам захочется настроить именно стандартный ярлык, а у вас Windows 8й версии и старше - найти его вы можете с помощью опции "Перейти к расположению файла":

[image: скриншот]